# Very Delayed Choice Experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment

I am trying to really understand this experiment. Some talk about retrocausality. Others give a fair explanation of why that is NOT the case.

Lets say we setup our experiment, and photons are divided and half goes to the screen where a pattern will be shown and the other half are sent to detectors on moon surface, 1.3 light seconds away.

Our gun can fire enough photons (one by one) in one second to show a pattern.

What pattern will appear during the first second, before our detectors show from which slit it came from? (I know about the called  fallacy of “which slit”, lets let this subject aside for a moment).

I am no expert, only a very curious person. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to put a beamsplitter downstream from a pair of slits to produce two pairs of beams, so that one of the pairs overlap on a screen and the other pair land separately on detectors corresponding to each of the beams in the other pair.  On the screen you will see an interference pattern that builds up from the arrival of a lot of photons that **can't** be traced back to individual slits; and at the detectors you will get a lot of "clicks" announcing the arrival of photons that **can** be traced to individual slits -- but the photons at the detectors will not be the same photons detected at the screen.

A photon is detected once, and once only, which is true also (of course) in the case where the second beam travels to the Moon before the photons that it contains are detected.  No photon that is detected at one place is also detected at another place. Put the screen on the moon and the slit-identifying detectors on the earth, and it's still true.

Comment: Thks McGrew. I just wanted to put the delayed choice experiment to the limit. Breaking photons with a cristal, and sending to “the moon” (teatrical only), is one way to do that.

Comment: I understand your point. BUT, as photons are fired one by one, we would know the order they would appear in the earth screen, and we would know if the “clicks” would come up in detector 1 or 2 in the moon, and that is not allowed. Sorry to insist.

Comment: OK, here's a thought experiment.  Suppose you fire one photon through the system.  You detect a photon on the screen. How can a detector somewhere else, sampling a split-off portion of the beam, tell you which slit that photon went through?  Remember that once the photon is detected, it can't be detected again.  It went to the screen and that's the end of that photon.